# How to store unused Macbook battery for long period of time?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

I'm going on a long backpacking trip and going to leave my Macbook at home unused. How should I store its battery to maximize the battery life?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Battery technology used by Apple is no different than other laptops. They're all Li-ion cells.

Apparently, the recommended practice for extended storage is to get the battery down to 40% and store it in a cool place, possibly the refrigerator.

Some relevant sources:

1. http://www.runpcrun.com/laptop-battery-use-and-storage-guidelines
2. http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/how_to_prolong_lithium_based_batteries